# Angular2 - where do I put all the logic between the component and service?

Tags: angular, typescript

in my project I have the following:

Component which calls a service class which calls an API. The logic I need to add is specific to the UI only.

This pretty clean and simple, however I have some binding and logic to add and have added it in the component which doesn't seem like the best solution. I'm thinking of a middle ground between the component and service class to do the job which will split it out. Is this a good idea? What is the best practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the majority of cases a `service`, a `component` and and a `class` to modelate the object you are dealing with are enough.

The component should have everything related to the UI you are displaying and the appropriate linkers to services, whilst the service should not know about the UI at all (generally used for API calls).

In some cases an `/util.ts` file might be appropiate to save functions which you are reusing over your site, but generally not. Note that these functions cannot be attached to any component / service in particular.

If you want further abstraction on certain fields, which you probably need as soon as that component has too many responsibilities, the best is to create another module and exchange data through `EventEmitter` and properties. [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html)

**Edit:**

Since you are asking for references to best practices, the best if for you to read [John Papa's Angular2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#app-structure-and-angular-modules) ones. You will want to adhere to [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#single-responsibility) and [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#app-structure-and-angular-modules).

Answer (score 0):

Usually its the components in Angular 2 where we should write the logic for bindings etc.

Comment: @BPDI but wouldn't that result in a thick component class? Ideally the component should be thin shouldn't it?

Comment: There is nothing as such that components has to be thin. Angular is based upon typescript and ES6 pattern wherein we use decorators for linking and binding the values. You can refer  [this](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html)   for more information